# How to use "'try" in R to skip error in for-loop

Tags: r, loops

every one.

I would like to ask something about how to avoid a possible error message within a for loop. I am running a simulation and in some repetitions there may be an error that will cause a crash and stop the whole procedure, what I want is to simply move on to the next iteration automatically and discard the "bad" repetitions from my results.

```
The code is as below.

    >    for(j in 1:100){ 
    > p<-YHatMulti(theta,X)   
    >  z=dim(p)[1] 
    >  A[[1,1]]<-matrix(apply(apply(cbind(p,X,((1+m-1):(z+m-1))),1,function(x){-x[1]*(1-x[1])*x[3:6]%*%t(x[3:6])*lambda^(((z+m-1)-x[7])/(1000-1)^r)}),1,sum),4,4)
    > A[[2,2]]<-matrix(apply(apply(cbind(p,X,((1+m-1):(z+m-1))),1,function(x){-x[2]*(1-x[2])*x[3:6]%*%t(x[3:6])*lambda^(((z+m-1)-x[7])/(1000-1)^r)}),1,sum),4,4)
    > A[[1,2]]<-matrix(apply(apply(cbind(p,X,((1+m-1):(z+m-1))),1,function(x){x[1]*(x[2])*x[3:6]%*%t(x[3:6])*lambda^(((z+m-1)-x[7])/(1000-1)^r)}),1,sum),4,4)
    > A[[2,1]]<-A[[1,2]]                                                    
    > A_rows<-lapply(1:2,bind_A_row)   Amatrix<-do.call(cbind,A_rows)  
    > Amatrix[is.na(Amatrix)]<-0  
    > B<--apply(cbind(t(sweep(t(X),2,YMat[,1]-p[,1],'*')),t(sweep(t(X),2,YMat[,2]-p[,2],'*')))*(lambda^(((z+m-1)-(1+m-1):(z+m-1))/1000^r)),2,sum)
    > B<-as.matrix(B)   B[is.na(B)]<-0   
    > #B<-B+t(Amatrix%*%(as.matrix(as.vector(t(theta)))))
    >  theta<-as.vector(t(theta))+t(ginv(Amatrix)%*%as.matrix(B))  
    > theta<-matrix(data = theta, ncol= ncol(X), nrow  = typeY-1, byrow =
    > TRUE) 
     }
```

The last third line use "ginv". I found sometimes, the matrix B will have NA element. Thus the loop will be end.

Can some one help me use "try" to skip this error? Since I am doing simulation, I can skip this error and take the next simulation.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps `tryCatch(ginv(...), error=function(e) NULL)` would be a good start. After the call, check with `!is.null` and either continue with `theta` or just skip it with `next`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving an error message, I think you can use the `tryCatch` function. You can try with something like:

```
theta <- tryCatch({ as.vector(t(theta))+t(ginv(Amatrix)%*%as.matrix(B)) },
                    error = function(e){ next })
```